# macOS creates "by itself" a new directory and moves files to it

Tags: icloud

When searching for some of my files, which are supposed to be in the `~/Documents` folder, I found that they have been moved into a new folder `~/Documents/Documents - XXX`, where XXX is the name I gave to my computer back then when have set it up for the first time.

I for sure did not knowingly create such a folder, let alone move the files into it. Looking at the Folder with Finder, I see a small **download** icon next to it, and some of the filenames now end in `.icloud`, so I guess this mysterious hijacking of my files must be related somehow to iCloud.

I darkly remember having changed some iCloud settings, if I remember correctly, I enabled Pages to back up its data on iCloud, but I don't see how this could created this weird shuffling around of my documents. Does perhaps the `Documents` folder have some built-in magic related to iCloud?

Can someone suggest what was going on here?

macOS 12.6.9

Comment: Did you turn on the **Desktop and Documents** sync for some reason?

Comment: @MarcWilson: No sure. I was playing with the sync options and it could be that I turned it on, but soon after off again. What exactly is it doing?