# I would like to see my Documents folder in Finder

Tags: finder, folders, smart-folders

My feeling is that this problem is somehow related to my question [macOS creates "by itself" a new directory and moves files to it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467220/macos-creates-by-itself-a-new-directory-and-moves-files-to-it):

I can see my `Documents` folder from my zsh command line:

```
1-0-12:19) ~: command ls -ld D*
drwx------@  3 ronaldfischer  staff   96  2 Oct 11:27 Desktop
drwx------@ 11 ronaldfischer  staff  352 27 Dec 17:02 Documents
drwx------+ 18 ronaldfischer  staff  576 28 Dec 09:04 Downloads
lrwxr-xr-x   1 ronaldfischer  staff   49 14 Apr  2023 Dropbox -> /Users/ronaldfischer/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox
(1-0-12:19) ~: stat Documents
16777221 12904042042 drwx------ 11 ronaldfischer staff 0 352 "Dec 27 17:02:04 2023" "Dec 27 17:02:02 2023" "Dec 28 08:26:55 2023" "Jan  1 01:00:00 1970" 4096 0 0 Documents
```

But when I open `Finder` I don't see this folder, though I see all other entries in my home directory:

[image: Finder in my home dir]

Of course I can do from the command line something like

```
open $HOME/Documents
```

and then see the content of this directory, but why can't Finder show me its content when it displays the entries in $HOME? What is so special with this folder?

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment by *nohillside*, I wanted to verify whether "Documents in iCloud is enabled or disabled". I googled the following recommendation for doing so:

1. Open Finder and go to the iCloud Drive folder.
2. Drag an item to the Trash, or move it to a different folder on your Mac.

Clicking on iCloud Drive in folder brings up the following picture:

[image: iCloud Drive]

However I can so see what i can infer from this picture. We see that it contains a folder named `Documents`, but it also contains a folder named i.e. `Downloads`, and I *do* see a `Downloads` folder in my Finder inside the home directory; I just don't see a `Documents` folder. So what is the difference between `Documents` and `Downloads`?

For the safe side, I checked my iPafd and went there to iCloud drive in the file manager, and I did find there a folder `Dowloads` with the same content than in my Mac (so this folder is obviously shared), and another folder named `Dokumente` (which is German for "documents"), and contains the same content as the `Documents` folder inside my MacOS.

So I guess this is somehow shared as well.  Interestingly, there is one subdirectory in `Documents` (respectively `Dokumente`) which is named `Documents - Ronald’s MacBook Pro` (including the spaces and special characters), which contains all that original stuff I had previously in my Documents folder.

I would like to end up in a situation, where my MacBook has its own Documents folder, and this folder should contain the content which is now `Documents - Ronald’s MacBook Pro`. I don't mind the `Downloads` folder continues to be shared.

I don't want to loose any files; what would be the recommended process then? I would like to sketch my idea how to solve the problem first, and ask you to approve it as correct, or suggest a better way. Note that I'm using zsh:

First i back up the important stuff:

```
cd 
mkdir DocumentsOriginal
mv -r 'Documents/Documents - Ronald’s MacBook Pro/*(D)' DocumentsOriginal
```

rmdir 'Documents/Documents - Ronald’s MacBook Pro/*(D)'

Now I have two directories: The stuff which still is visible in `Documents` (and hence also in the `Dokumente` folder on the iPad) is stuff I want to **keep** shared, perhaps under a new name `DocumentsShared`. The stuff which is now in `DocumentsOriginal` is what I want to have only on my MacBook. How to achieve this? Of course I could now do a

```
mv Documents DocumentsShared
mv Documents Original Documents
```

but I doubt that this will tell iCloud about my intentions, because I fear that my local  `Documents` is still coupled somehow to the `Dokumente` folder on the iPad.

As for the name, I do not insist that the folders are named differently on MacBook and iPad. Actually I prefer having shared folders named the same accross devices, and I find the current Documents/Dokumente naming confusing. So if I would end up seeing a folder `DocumentsShared` on the iPad instead of the present `Dokumente` folder, this would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: Do you have a recent/up to date backup of Documents and Desktop, ideally on an external drive? If not, **ensure you have a backup before proceeding**.

Then, follow the instructions in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985 to check whether Documents/Desktop are stored in iCloud and turn it off if it is still on.